# Laravel: Many To Many relationship with only 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many

I am trying to implement a tagging feature into a small piece of software and for simplicity reasons I'd like to actually only use two tables, just like so:

```
items (first table)
- id (int)
- title (string)
- description (string)

item_tag (second "pivot" table)
- item_id (int, foreign key to item.id)
- tag_name (string (!))
(primary_key(item_id, tag_name))
```

With the models

```
<?php

class Item extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('title', 'desription');

    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'item_tag', 'item_id', 'tag_name');
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php

class Tag extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('tag_name');

    public function items() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Item', 'item_tag', 'item_id', 'tag_name');
    }
}
```

However, I can't seem to get this working as the `belongsToMany` function seems to expect three tables and anyway Laravel seems to want a `tags` table. I know, that my plan of using only two tables is not really elegant as it increases redundancy, but still it would be acceptable for my use case. So is there any quick solution for this?

Comment: That's not 'many to many' because the tag name isn't unique. Each tag/item combination is its own unique ID. Yes, you are making many tags link to many items, but the tags themselves aren't unique.

Comment: You made a one to many relationship. For a many to many relationship you need 3 tabels: two for the information (each informarion is unique) and one to connect them.

Comment: You should be using three tables and have a many to many relationship. You say you're using two tables for simplicity but it's not simpler, and it's it's basically no extra effort to do it right the first time.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a `belongsToMany` relationship but a `hasMany`. Each item has many tags.

The problem with this approach is that if in the future you want to change the name of a tag or add an extra field such as a description, you will have to do an update of all the database rows with that tag. It's much easier to just have a dedicated table for the tags, like so :

```
tags
- id (int)
- name (string)
```

And setup your pivot table like so :

```
item_tag
- id (int)
- item_id (int)
- tag_id (int)
```

This way, you can easily change the name of a tag, add an extra column and things like that, without ever needing to affect more than one entry.

Once you have these three tables (couting the items one you have), your `belongsToMany` relationships will work, and you don't even have to specify the name of the primary keys/table, as long as you follow the proper naming scheme.